# ValueError: 'pyart_HomeyerRainbow' is not a valid value for name

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I'm having trouble with this pyart color map. Everyone else who used the code had it work, so I know it's a problem on my end.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
import cartopy.crs as crs
from cartopy.feature import NaturalEarthFeature
import numpy as np
import pyart
from wrf import (to_np, getvar, smooth2d, get_cartopy, cartopy_xlim,
                 cartopy_ylim, latlon_coords)
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) 

times = ['000070']
level = 1
for t in times:

# Open the NetCDF file

        ncfile = Dataset("/data/scratch/a/jtrapp/H_CTRL/cm1out_"+t+".nc") 
# MW runs:
        #ncfile = Dataset("/data/relamp/a/mjwoods3/bluewaters_cm1/May_20th/control_wrf/cm1out_"+t+".nc") 
        ncfile['vmove'][0]
        dbz = ncfile['dbz'][0,32,:,:]
        u = ncfile['uinterp'][0,level,:,:]
        v = ncfile['vinterp'][0,level,:,:]
        UH = ncfile['uh'][0,:,:]
        UH2 = np.where(UH < 100, 0, UH)
        
        x = ncfile['xh'][:]
        y = ncfile['yh'][:]
        
        X,Y = np.meshgrid(x[0::3],y[0::3])
        clevs = np.arange(10,75,1)

        plt.figure(figsize=(8,8), dpi=500)

        cf = plt.contourf(x, y, dbz, levels=clevs, cmap=get_cmap('pyart_HomeyerRainbow'))
        #cf2 = plt.contour(x, y, UH, linewidths=0.75, alpha=0.6)
#        cf2 = plt.contour(x, y, UH2, levels=[-1,100,500], colors=['white','black','red'], linewidths=0.75, alpha=0.75)
       # plt.quiver(X,Y,u[0::3,0::3],v[0::3,0::3], scale=500, headwidth=10, headlength=10, headaxislength=5, width=0.0005, pivot='middle')
        plt.title('Simulated Reflectivity at '+str(t)+'s (1.25 km AGL)', fontsize=14, pad=3)
        plt.xlabel('X-distance (km)', fontsize=8)
        plt.ylabel('Y-distance (km)', fontsize=8)
        plt.colorbar(cf,fraction=0.05, pad=0.02, label='dBZ')
        
        # Display the plot
        plt.savefig('/data/scratch/a/jtrapp/ref'+t+'.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

I'd rather not change the colormap if possible. I've tried updating pyart and deleting/reinstalling, but I'm pretty new to coding and don't know what else to try. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to identify the exact error without more information, such as the error message or output. However, there are a few things that might cause problems in this code:

There is a line ncfile['vmove'][0] which doesn't do anything with the returned value. It is possible that this line is causing an error or unexpected behavior.

In the line cf = plt.contourf(x, y, dbz, levels=clevs, cmap=get_cmap('pyart_HomeyerRainbow')), the cmap argument is set to get_cmap('pyart_HomeyerRainbow'), but it is possible that pyart_HomeyerRainbow is not a recognized color map. You may need to use a different color map or check that pyart_HomeyerRainbow is a valid color map.

In the line plt.colorbar(cf,fraction=0.05, pad=0.02, label='dBZ'), the label argument is set to 'dBZ', but it is possible that dBZ is not the correct units for the data being plotted. You may need to check the units and adjust the label accordingly.

I would recommend adding print statements or using a debugger to see if these issues are causing errors or unexpected behavior, or checking the documentation for the relevant libraries to ensure that the parameters being used are correct.